# Java - printing one character at a time using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, newline

I'm trying to print one character at a time from a string recursively such as:

```
    a
    va
    ava
    Java
     Java
    o Java
    lo Java
    llo Java
    ello Java
    Hello Java
```

But my code below:

```
    public static String displayStuffR(String x){
        return displayStuffR(0,x);
        }
    public static String displayStuffR(int i,String x){
        if (i<x.length()){
            return x.substring(x.length()-1-i) + displayStuffR(i+1,x);}
        return x;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
       System.out.print(displayStuffR("Hello Java"));
     }
```

Displays:

```
   avaavaJava Javao Javalo Javallo Javaello JavaHello JavaHello Java
```

Much help would be appreciated

Comment: You can add line feed to Strings by using adding `"\n"`

Comment: Actually since you're appending to a string you will need to append \n at some point in your displayStuffR(int, String) function. Also, a question: in your desired output, should the second line be "va"?

Comment: @thesentiment Yes it should be va i was typing this quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return a string at that time use new line for the string returned in display function something like this

`return x.substring(x.length()-1-i)+"\n" + displayStuffR(i+1,x);`

and update your if condition to

`i < x.length()-1`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you may use this method.

```
static void  recursivePrint(String text) {
    if (text.length() == 0)
        return;

    recursivePrint(text.substring(1, text.length()));
    System.out.println(text);
}
```